# Can't connect to docker via SSH when VPN is connected

Tags: ssh, vpn

I using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and FortiClient VPN application.

Everything works fine apart from when I'm trying to connect my docker container via SSH (localhost) I get the following error: "kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer Connection reset by 127.0.0.1 port 2222". More that that, when I'm NOT on VPN - I dont have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

try to define your docker interface when trying to connect

```
ssh -b interface-ip remote-ip
```

interface-ip = docker ip usually 172.x.x.x
remote ip is container ip

Answer (score 0):

Check your sockets, is yours currently occupied?

Run:

```
> netstat -vatn | xargs grep 2222
```